# how to point spring cloud config server to a folder decided by client if git is the version control

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Am trying spring cloud config server and client as stand-alone separate applications.

on git, i have folder structure like below-

my-config 
----projectfolder1 
--------application.properties 
----projectfolder2 
--------application.properties

I would like that spring cloud client named "projectfolder1" should search  
application.properties within projectfolder1 on git from spring cloud server i.e  
----projectfolder1 
--------application.properties

and  client "projectfolder2" should get  the below mentioned properties from spring cloud config server  
----projectfolder2 
--------application.properties

My Spring Cloud Config server application.properties has- 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths='{application}'

projectfolder1 in its bootstrap.properties has
spring.application.name=projectfolder1

and projectfolder2 in its bootstrap.properties has
spring.application.name=projectfolder2

According to spring cloud config documentation '{application}' in search path should find the files within the "resolved application name" folder on git. But the above '{application}' doesn't work for me. Clients projectfolder1 and projectfolder2 are not able to get any property at all.

pls assist. i know its possible duplicate of another question on stack overflow. but that question is not resolved  and i do not have rights to comment on any question being a new user, So i created this as another question here.

Comment: Please update your formatting to make it more readable.

Comment: Updated the formatting. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.
The trick is to give search-path {application}  without quotes as given below.
It was a little tricky as spring documentation mentions it as '{application}' , probably spring developers just wanted to highlight it with quotes.

spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths={application} 
instead of 
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths='{application}'